# Dynamic ngClass name

Tags: angular, angular-directive, ng-class

I have a task to add several classes to an element, one of them has to be conditional. I looked in docs and found this:

```
<some-element [ngClass]="{'first': true, 'second': true, 'third': false}">...</some-element>
```

But the problem is that the other class has to have a dynamic name from a variable, I wanted to do something like this:

```
[ngClass]="{
        [menuItem.class]: true,
        'open': router.url.split('/')[1] === menuItem.path
      }">
```

And I got this error

```
Unexpected token [, expected identifier, keyword, or string
```

Any Ideas how to realize what I want to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what I ended up with is to use a couple of ways to add classes demand on its conditions:

- some classes via `[ngClass]="classObj"` syntax
- some via `[ngClass]="classArray"`
- some via `[class.class-name]="condition"`
- some via vanilla HTML syntax `class="className"`

Answer (score 1):

**ngClass** can accept object so you can build object and assign to property and that acceptable

component

```
classObj = {hover:true , 'drop-shadow underline' : false}
```

template

```
<div [ngClass]="classObj"></div>
```

[ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)

Comment: The problem is that I have an array `menuItems` in the component and I iterate through it only in the template. I don't actually want to iterate three times: in the component for creating an array of classes, after it in the template once for outputting items and one more time for outputting their classes...